# How to build multiple drill down using highchart correctly?

Tags: php, highcharts, yii, yii2

I want to make multiple drill down chart using framework `Yii2`. I want to make student's chart based by age. I have installed highcharts via composer. I also have registered it to my `php` file, but I don't know why the drilldown chart doesn't work. I think, it's because my incorrect codes.

Here is my tables:

**facultyin2011**

[image]

**department2011**

[image]

**major2011**

[image]

**Here is my controller:**

```
<?php
    namespace app\controllers;

    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\helpers\Json;



    class MagisterrinciController extends Controller
    {
         public function actionIndex()
    {


//data usia fakultas
        $faculty = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Faculty'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $age1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $age2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('facultyin2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $age1 = array_map('floatval', $age1);
        $age2 = array_map('floatval', $age2);


        $data['ageforfacultystudent'] = json_encode($faculty);
        $data['age1'] = json_encode($age1);
        $data['age2'] = json_encode($age2);


// next
        $department = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['Department'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agedepartment1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agedepartment2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $agedepartment1 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment1);
        $agedepartment2 = array_map('floatval', $agedepartment2);


        $data['agefordepartmentstudent'] = json_encode($department);
        $data['agedepartment1'] = json_encode($agedepartment1);
        $data['agedepartment2'] = json_encode($agedepartment2);


//next

        $majorstudent = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['major'])
            ->from('major2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['lessthan25'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();

        $agemajor2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
            ->select(['btween25to29'])
            ->from('department2011')
            ->limit(10)
            ->column();


        $agemajor1 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor1);
        $agemajor2 = array_map('floatval', $agemajor2);


        $data['ageformajorstudent'] = json_encode($majorstudent);
        $data['agemajor1'] = json_encode($agemajor1);
        $data['agemajor2'] = json_encode($agemajor2);





        return $this->render('index',$data);
        }


    }
```

**Here is my index view:**

```
<?php
    use app\assets\HighchartsAsset;


    HighchartsAsset::register($this);
    $this->title = 'Highcharts Test';
    ?>



<!-- data selanjutnya -->    
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<div class="x_panel">
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
 <?php $this->registerJs("

$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Basic drilldown'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: $ageforfacultystudent
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                name: 'lessthan25',
                data: $age1,
                drilldown: 'department1'
            },
            {
                name: 'btween25to29',
                data: $age2,
                drilldown: 'department2'
            }],

        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'department1',
                name: 'Departemen',
                data: [{
                    name: 'lessthan25',
                    data: $agedepartment1,
                    drilldown: 'major1'
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'btween25to29',
                    data: $agedepartment2,
                    drilldown: 'major2'
                }
                ]
            }, {

                id: 'major1',
                data: $agemajor1
            },
            {

                id: 'major2',
                data: $agemajor2
            }]
        }
    })
});
")?>

</div>
</div>
```

here is the result:

[image]

those charts can't be drilled down.

When I checked the console, there is no error message.

[image]
Could anybody please correct my codes above? It's gonna help me a lot. Thank you in advance

Comment: [This](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts) perhaps makes your life a little bit easier

Comment: I have used those codes. But my drilldown chart still doesn't work @gms Could you please check my codes above? Maybe there are some incorrect codes there, but I dont know how to correct them

Comment: In the code you posted you are not using the module I linked. If you still do not want to use it and you prefer to stick to your own solution, you should provide at least what is the error(s) you are having

Comment: I have edited my questions and I have told what is the error that I'm having. I post the result of my codes on my question. The error is when I click one of the charts, it can't be drilled down @gmc

Comment: I guess some js error is showing in your console. Post it

Comment: there is no error message in console :( @gmc

Comment: I don't know if it has something to do with your problem, but you have to close some `<div>` you open but do not close. Try to fix that first

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: I think you are creating a `data` array from the `drilldown` wrong. In the [docs example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown) it is an array of arrays, not an array of json objects

Comment: do you know how to correct my codes above? @gms My highchart is a little bit different with the link that you gave me because I took data from database